# Measure Stream Latency in RTSP Stream

Tags: android, stream, rtsp, latency

I have a RTSP server to stream data and an android client. In client I have used "VideoView" widget of android to play the stream. I have just given the url of server to VideoView and started it. So I have not written any code to stream and decode the data. I want to measure the stream latency in this case.

Is there some way to measure the latency in this case?